# Dice probability puzzle

Tags: probability, puzzle, dice

What is the probability of a run of at least 3 sixes when a die is thrown 5 times?

I think I have the answer but from what I have been told its not the correct answer. Would someone like to help?

Comment: Could you give your answer and the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks to your comment below about ignoring a sequence, I've managed to reconcile my answer with the actual answer. I'm going to update it once everyone has had their shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply count all the cases:

Possibilities for three consecutive $6$s but no four consecutive $6$s:

The sequence be of the one of these three forms:

$ 666XY  , X666X , YX666$

where the $X$'s can be chosen from $1,\dots ,5$ and the $Y$'s are also allowed to be $6$. So we get

$5\cdot6 + 5\cdot5 + 5\cdot6$

possibilities for this case.

Possibilities for four consective digits:

$6666X$ and $X6666$

So those are $5 + 5 $ possibilites.

And $1$ case where all the dice are $6$s.

So the probability is

$$p= \frac{5\cdot6 + 5\cdot5 + 5\cdot6 + 5 +5 +1}{6^5} = \frac{16}{6^4} = \frac{1}{3^4} $$

Answer (score 6):

Presumably a run means consecutive.

The run might begin with the first toss. This has probability $(1/6)^3$.

The run might begin with the second toss. This has probability $(5/6)(1/6)^3$.

The run might begin with the third toss.  This also has probability $(5/6)(1/6)^3$.

Add these three numbers.

Comment: Should we not separate the following cases:                                 1. we get first 3 as sixes and then some other number.            2. first four sixes and then some other number.                   3. first five sixes?

Comment: There is no need to. If you do it correctly, you will still get the right answer. Of course you must not forget about runs that start later like $2666$. My answer gets them all.

Comment: You are missing one case.

Comment: Your third term should be (5/6)(1/6^3). For cases like 61666.

Comment: If you can change your answer, I'm going to accept it as a correct one.

Comment: ;@InnocentRetard    You are right, starting at $3$ is also $(5/6)(1/6)^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about 6 and just look for the probability of at least three consecutives.
In the sequel **s** stands for 'toss has ***same*** result as preceding toss', **d** stands  for 'toss has ***different*** result as preceding toss' We start with the second toss. Possibilities are:

**ss**        with probability (1/6)x(1/6)

**sdss**      with probability (1/6)x(5/6)x(1/6)x(1/6)

**dss**       with probability (5/6)x(1/6)x(1/6)

**ddss**      with probability (5/6)x(5/6)x(1/6)x(1/6)

summation gives 2/27. If you do this for 6 (or any other) specifically you get (2/27)x(1/6)=1/81.
At [this place](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504693/75923) you will find a formula for this.

Comment: @Kumar If e.g. the first toss is a $4$ then $\textbf{ss}$ stands for event $444\cdot\cdot$, and $\textbf{sdss}$ stands for  $44kkk$ where $k\neq 4$, $\textbf{dss}$ stands for $4kkk\cdot$ and $\textbf{ddss}$ stands for $4klll$ where $k\neq4$ and $l\neq k$. So **all distinct possibilities** of occuring $3$ consecutives within $5$ tosses are captured so that summation of these probabilities gives the probability of occuring $3$ consecutives. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Yes. I am fine. but I guess this example of yours should be in the answer. It would be slightly more easy for the reader to understand and comprehend.:)

Comment: @Kumar On this I agree with you. This answer is not very "OP-friendly" and an example would have improved that.