# Probability of losing $n$ consecutive rounds of a total of $k$

Tags: probability, gambling

If there is a constant probability $p$ of winning a round of a game such that each game is independent of every other, what is the probability $P$ of losing $n$ consecutive rounds out of a total of $k$?

In the simple case where $k$=$n$, $P=(1-p)^n$. However, I was not able to work out a formula in any case where $k>n,k\in \mathbb{N}$.

I've tried several approaches, including:

1. As events are independent, the streak is equally likely to occur at any point. There are $k-n$ points where the streak could start, and the probability of a streak occurring at any point is $(1-p)^n$, so $P=(k-n)(1-p)^n$. However, I believe this double counts streaks of length $n+1$ as two $n$ length streaks, and in some cases this may be greater than $1$ if $p$ is quite low and $k-n$ is high.
2. A binomial distribution can model the probability that there are $x$ losses, if $x\geq n$. We can sum over all possible values of $x$ and multiply the probability of $x$ total losses by the probability of $n$ consecutive losses given $x$ total losses using permutations and combinations. However, I could not work out how to correctly calculate the probability of $n$ or more consecutive losses given $x$ total losses out of $k$ events.

Can anyone help me solve this deceptively simple problem? I am trying to perform risk analysis, where $n$ is the number of successive investments I can afford to lose out of a total of $k$. Currently I am estimating these values using a primitive computer simulation, but it would be much better if I could calculate (or at least approximate) the true probability in a reasonable amount of time.

**Update**: [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62297) is a computationally viable approach to solving an almost identical problem relying on Markov chains which I've tested and it generalises wonderfully.

Comment: I think I have an approach that will work for this, but it's a bit late so I need to work on it a bit more... What are the odds of hitting that streak starting with the first round? Second Round? Third Round? Do any of these change with the total number of rounds?

Comment: Maybe worth a read: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234062/probability-of-tossing-a-fair-coin-with-at-least-k-consecutive-heads?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124684/probability-of-getting-a-sequence-of-at-least-k-heads-in-n-coin-flips, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21825/probability-of-a-run-of-k-successes-in-a-sequence-of-n-bernoulli-trials, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491836/probability-of-finding-at-least-k-consecutive-heads-in-n-coin-tosses

Comment: Should it be exactly one sequence  of lost rounds of length $n$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of tossing a fair coin with at least $k$ consecutive heads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234062/probability-of-tossing-a-fair-coin-with-at-least-k-consecutive-heads)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: @user any number of sequences of length $\geq n$ qualifies.

Comment: @YaniorWeg whilst that question is almost the same, the answers presented do not generalise to the case where $p \neq 0.5$, and they are computationally intractable. However, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62297), linked to by Minus One-Twelfth on stats.SE solves my problem. If you can't mark it as a duplicate of that question though, I'll close this question.